# Step by step solution of a limit of a sequence - Calling Wolfram|Alpha in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries, education

I'd like to visualiza the step-by-step solution of the following limit by calling Wolfram|Alpha in Mathematica, but I don't know how to specify that n is a positive integer variable:

```
WolframAlpha["lim(n*(2^(1/n)-1)) as n->+infinity", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The limit does not require n to be an integer. The fact that the limit is for n approaching +Infinity implies that n is positive. Use `WolframAlpha["lim(n*(2^(1/n)-1)) as n->+infinity", {{"Limit", 2}, 
  "Content"}, 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution", 
   "Limit__Step-by-step solution"}]`

Comment: Hello @BobHanlon, can you clarify me why the fact that n is a positive integer is not important please?

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: W|A does not properly work with DiscreteLimit (in Wolfram Language notation). Consider WolframAlpha["Limit[(-1)^n/n ,n->Infinity]", PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}] . [CASE:4384509] was submitted by me.

Comment: `FunctionDomain[n*(2^(1/n) - 1), n]` indicates that the function is real for all real n not equal to zero. Look at `LogLinearPlot[{Log[2], n*(2^(1/n) - 1)}, {n, 1, 10000}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon in your opinion, to know the formal mathematical reason that ensures me that the two limits are the same (n positive integer and n real), do I have to ask the question on Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yes, asking there would be better.